# Additional Data being appended to CKEditor String

Tags: ckeditor, http-post, fckeditor, string-length

When i type 1960 characters in CKEditor and submit the form, my controller is getting around 2000 characters. I have checked through the data but still cant find out the exact reason why it is going like that

Length of data in UI : **1978**
Length of data in Controller : **1991**

so, additional 13 characters are added.

**The data i am sending in UI is as follows --------------------------------------**

Some older driver versions allowed you to select the “letter” size and adjust the margins to define the ticket size.  This feature is still available in the new drivers to support old installations.
  
 When selecting a new font, Windows will default to the previous font size.  This size will usually be incorrect.  You must re-assign a valid font size to guarantee the proper font representation on your screen.  "Tall" font in Word Pad does not display properly on the screen.
  
 **Driver Use – Word Only (PCL and FGL)**
 Before using Word, you must select the “use printer metrics to layout document” box in tools/options/compatibility.  All of the previous “driver use” guidelines apply to Word.  Word also provides you with the unique ability to define a custom page size within the application itself.  We strongly recommend **against** the use of this feature.  However, the following description will explain the use and limitations of this feature.
  
 While Word allows you to manipulate the page size in both portrait and landscape modes, the data sent to the printer only functions properly in portrait mode.  You **cannot** print in landscape mode with a Word defined custom page size.
  
 In portrait mode, you can manually set the height for any ticket length up to 11 inches.  For ticket lengths greater than 11 inches, you will need to add your own page size as described above in the “all applications” section.
 lengths greater than 11 inches, you will need to add your own page size as described above in the “all applications” section.
 lengths greater than 11 inches, you will need to add your own page size as described above in the “all applications” section.
 lengths greater than
  **

**The data im receiving in controller  is as follows --------------------------------------**

Some older driver versions allowed you to select the “letter” size and adjust the margins to define the ticket size.  This feature is still available in the new drivers to support old installations.
 
When selecting a new font, Windows will default to the previous font size.  This size will usually be incorrect.  You must re-assign a valid font size to guarantee the proper font representation on your screen.  "Tall" font in Word Pad does not display properly on the screen.
 
**Driver Use – Word Only (PCL and FGL)**
Before using Word, you must select the “use printer metrics to layout document” box in tools/options/compatibility.  All of the previous “driver use” guidelines apply to Word.  Word also provides you with the unique ability to define a custom page size within the application itself.  We strongly recommend **against** the use of this feature.  However, the following description will explain the use and limitations of this feature.
 
While Word allows you to manipulate the page size in both portrait and landscape modes, the data sent to the printer only functions properly in portrait mode.  You **cannot** print in landscape mode with a Word defined custom page size.
 
In portrait mode, you can manually set the height for any ticket length up to 11 inches.  For ticket lengths greater than 11 inches, you will need to add your own page size as described above in the “all applications” section.
lengths greater than 11 inches, you will need to add your own page size as described above in the “all applications” section.
lengths greater than 11 inches, you will need to add your own page size as described above in the “all applications” section.
lengths greater than

Answer (score 0):

I depends on the way you are requesting the output, but this can be spaces or this could also be some \n\r tags for all the 
 that you have inserted.

Did you try already to see the differences in short texts, to find you what it is exactly?

I think it are some \n\r tags, you should see these tags when you request the data in you code.. If not i'm sure it are spaces.